# CodeIgniter call protected method of another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two classes on my Codeigniter project: Users and Profiles

Users:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller 
{
   ...
```

Profiles:

```
class Profiles extends CI_Controller 
{
   protected function create_user_profile()
   {
      ....
   }
   ...
```

When a user is created by user controller, a profile should be created immediately. So a function in Users has to call `create_user_profile` function. Now my question is:

If I make `create_user_profile` public, one can call it by URL. But if I keep it protected, then how to call it from User controller?

Is there a better way than moving `create_user_profile` from Profiles controller to Users controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a Profiles Library instead :

Libraries/profiles.php

```
class Profiles 
  {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->CI =& get_instance(); // Existing Code Igniter Instance
    }

    public function create_user_profile()
    {
      // Your Code Here
      // can communicate back with CI by using $this->CI
      // $this->CI->load->view(....);
      // $this->CI->load->model(...);
      // ETC
    }
  }
```

controllers/users.php

```
class Users extends CI_Controller 
  {
    public function my_function(){
      $this->load->library('profiles');
      $this->profiles->create_user_profile();    
    }
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use a model, but I agree a library appears to be the best option here.

Comment: i had a typo in my controller hehe, just fixed that up to avoid any confusion.. Im a big Codeigniter user, and find myself building libraries for almost everything. leaving my models for database templates.

Comment: thank you @BadWolf, I called `profile` model from `users` controller, and no need to call any method from `profile` controller anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a different, non-web-controller class. Then you can re-use it from everywhere.

Comment: what is non-web-controller class?

Comment: A generic class that does not extend CI_Controller

Comment: then calling model from it will be harder

Comment: then pass the model as an argument to the method

Comment: is there a way to make it public but prevent user to call from url?